# Draw solid square button and add custom font to it

Tags: android, button

I was wondering what the best way is to make a solid square button and to add a custom font to it.. I was thinking about a seperated class which handels the drawing (certain width= height depending of the width of the screen). Only thing I am wondering: how can I make it a button with a text? Do I place an button in my xml and is it possible to replace it with my self drawn button square?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to custom original button, you can add image as your button background via `android:background`. About custom font, You get button in activity and set custom `Typeface`.Put your font in `assets` folder.

```
Button txt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);  
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "1543Humane_jenson_bold.TTF");  
txt.setTypeface(font);
```

If you want to use this kind of button manytime you can create a custom button class similar to this

**CustomButton**

```
package com.example;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;

public class CustomButton extends Button {
        private static final String TAG = "TextView";

        public CustomButton (Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        public CustomButton (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            setCustomFont(context, attrs);
        }

        public CustomButton (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
            setCustomFont(context, attrs);
        }

        private void setCustomFont(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs) {
            TypedArray a = ctx.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomButton);
            String customFont = a.getString(R.styleable.TextViewPlus_customFont);
            setCustomFont(ctx, customFont);
            a.recycle();
        }

        public boolean setCustomFont(Context ctx, String asset) {
            Typeface tf = null;
            try {
            tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), asset);  
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not get typeface: "+e.getMessage());
                return false;
            }

        setTypeface(tf);  
        return true;
        }

}
```

**attrs.xml:** (in res/values)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="CustomButton ">
        <attr name="customFont" format="string"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

**main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:foo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.example.CustomButton 
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/showingOffTheNewTypeface"
        foo:customFont="custom.ttf">
    </com.example.CustomButton >
</LinearLayout>
```

Typeface class using HashMap to avoid memory problem. Change the `tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), asset);`   in `setCustomFont` with `tf= Typefaces.get(mContext, "cutomefont");`

```
    public class Typefaces{

private static final Hashtable<String, Typeface> cache = new Hashtable<String, Typeface>();

    public static Typeface get(Context c, String name){
        synchronized(cache){
            if(!cache.containsKey(name)){
                Typeface t = Typeface.createFromAsset(
                        c.getAssets(), 
                        String.format("fonts/%s.OTF", name)
                    );
                cache.put(name, t);
            }
            return cache.get(name);
        }
    }

}
```

[Another tut](http://vimaltuts.com/android-tutorial-for-beginners/android-custom-button) in Internet

Comment: Thanks, but I was just wondering, isn't it a little bit strange (and much slower) to set a custom button as background since I just want a solid square (no rounded corners or whatsoever)? Isn't it better and faster (if it is possible) to draw something out of Java and make that a button with text?

Comment: I don't really get your point (I understand that you want to customize button). Android provided component `Button`. If you want to customize button, you simple change attribute from xml. And Android do the draw for you. I only see others use draw some complex component.